# XSL IF is causing an error, removing it my code works. What is wrong?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following code. I am trying to use a simple IF within a FOR-EACH. I simplified it for this example here. When I add the follwowing IF (which in this example should always be true), my code bombs out. If I remove the IF test altogether, code runs fine.

```
  <xsl:if test="contains('apple','ap')">
```

Here is the full code:

```
        <xsl:for-each select="$external-doc/document(.)/items/item">
            <xsl:if test="contains('apple','ap')">
                <xsl:sort select="concat(substring(pubDate,7,4), substring(pubDate,1,2),substring(pubDate,4,2))" order="descending"/>
                <item>
                    <xsl:attribute name="href" select="concat($base-url,@href)"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="attribute()[not(name() = 'href')]|node()[not(name() = 'hero-image') and not(name() = 'image')]" /> 
                    <xsl:if test="image">
                        <image>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="not(contains(image/img/@src,'://'))">
                                    <img>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="src" select="concat($base-url,image/img/@src)"/>
                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="image/img/attribute()[not(name() = 'src')]" />
                                    </img>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise><xsl:apply-templates select="image/img" /></xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </image>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <searchtags>{string-join(tags/tag, ',')}</searchtags>
                </item> 
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

What am I doing wrong with the test?

Comment: That is  **not** "the full code". Please provide a short way to reproduce the problem, showing XML input, an executable XSLT stylesheet and expected output - see: [mcve]. If you're getting an error, quote the error message verbatim.

Comment: This is the only portion failing when the if statement is in there, there isn't any other code needed. In this example here, the if statement is true and should run. It doesn't. Removing the <xsl:if> and the corresponding tag, no error.

Comment: Please do not argue with the site requirements. Your code will not run as it is and I have no time to fill in the missing parts and/or remove the parts that will fail (such as an undefined variable right in the first line).

Answer (score 3):

I presume your error message says something like:

> XTSE0010  An xsl:if element must not contain an xsl:sort element

which is self-explanatory.

Comment: Actually my error message doesn't say this. The error message is hidden because the file ends up calling another stylesheet inside of a CMS. I did discover this though, moving the IF after the sort works just fine.

Comment: @JesseEarley, I would suggest to use a predicate in XPath instead e.g. to simply use `<xsl:for-each select="$external-doc/document(.)/items/item[contains('apple','ap')]"><xsl:sort ../>..</xsl:for-each>`